# Reading command line args from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh, command-line-arguments

I am trying to read a piece of text as a command line arg and print it out. This is my shell script (`script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

input=${1}
echo ${input}
```

This is how I am calling my script: `./script.sh Af)}R"}$;AF(@}#@]-`

Placing the command line argument in single quotes is not an option in this case. I am getting the following error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`)'`

I am new to shell script. Please help.

Comment: `)` is a special character in sh. You can't use it literally, it needs single quotes or a backslash.

Comment: You also need to quote the variable: `echo "$input"` -- using braces is not the same as using quotes.

Comment: `;` will be interpreted as the end of your command if it isn't escaped. Why is placing the argument in single quotes not an option?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Actually, I am trying to read in some text as part of a bigger program and I can't ask the end user to enter strings in `''`

Comment: Is the user entering the string on the command line, or are you feeding it to your script programmatically? I feel like something's missing.

Comment: @BenjaminW. The user enters some text which is read by a C program. This C program calls this shell script with this piece of text. In short, yes, this piece of text is being fed to the script programmatically.